# Adaptec Raid1 on Debian failed Stripes

Tags: debian-wheezy, raid1, adaptec, failed

its my 1st question here so please be kind.

I've got an monitoring server which is running on debian wheezy. It runs a RAID1 (2x 160GB) on a Adaptec Raid Controller (IBM ServeRAID 8k-l).

A few days ago on of the HDD failed. So i replaced it with another HDD with 250GB space (because there was no 160GB HD). Everthing looked fine, as the new HDD was replaced and the rebuilding have started. After it was finished, i got a massage from our Nagios raid_aac check:

```
there are some failed stripes on logical device 0 on controller 1!
```

In my opinion Raid1 doesn't work with Stripes so how could it be that i got this error message:

Output from the Adaptec Raid Controller:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Status                        : Optimal
   Channel description                      : SAS/SATA
   Controller Model                         : IBM ServeRAID 8k-l  
   Controller Serial Number                 : 1624F50
   Physical Slot                            : 0
   Installed memory                         : 32 MB
   Copyback                                 : Disabled
   Background consistency check             : Enabled
   Automatic Failover                       : Enabled
   Stayawake period                         : Disabled
   Spinup limit internal drives             : 0
   Spinup limit external drives             : 0
   Defunct disk drive count                 : 0
   Logical devices/Failed/Degraded          : 1/0/0
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Version Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   BIOS                                     : 5.2-0 (17003)
   Firmware                                 : 5.2-0 (17003)
   Driver                                   : 1.1-7 (28000)
   Boot Flash                               : 5.1-0 (15411)
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Battery Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Status                                   : Not Installed

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device number 0
   Logical device name                      : MIRROR
   RAID level                               : 1
   Status of logical device                 : Optimal
   Size                                     : 152499 MB
   Write-cache mode                         : Not supported
   Partitioned                              : Yes
   Protected by Hot-Spare                   : No
   Bootable                                 : Yes
   Failed stripes                           : Yes
   Power settings                           : Disabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Logical device segment information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Segment 0                                : Present (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:1)       PVFC44ZHT74KVE
   Segment 1                                : Present (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:0)      WD-WMAYP0M76S1V


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical Device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      Device #0
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 1.5 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,0(0:0)
         Reported Location                  : Enclosure 0, Slot 0
         Reported ESD(T:L)                  : 2,0(0:0)
         Vendor                             : WDC
         Model                              : WD2503ABYZ-011FA
         Firmware                           : 01.01S03
         Serial number                      : WD-WMAYP0M76S1V
         Size                               : 239429 MB
         Write Cache                        : Enabled (write-back)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         NCQ status                         : Disabled
      Device #1
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 1.5 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,1(1:0)
         Reported Location                  : Enclosure 0, Slot 1
         Reported ESD(T:L)                  : 2,0(0:0)
         Vendor                             : Hitachi
         Model                              : HDS721616PLA380
         Firmware                           : P22OABCA
         Serial number                      : PVFC44ZHT74KVE
         Size                               : 152627 MB
         Write Cache                        : Enabled (write-back)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         NCQ status                         : Disabled
      Device #2
         Device is an Enclosure services device
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 2,0(0:0)
         Enclosure ID                       : 0
         Type                               : SES2
         Vendor                             : IBM
         Model                              : SAS 2 DRIVE BP
         Firmware                           : 1.10
         Status of Enclosure services device
```

You guys got any hints, why i got this notification?

Do i have to replace the other 160GB HD as well with a 250GB HD because one of them got more space now, or do I really have to do a full backup and create a completely new array?

Comment: Go check. Run the nagios script from the command line. If it's a bash script, you can run it with `bash -x script` and it will literally tell you everything it does.

Comment: Nah its a perl Script. However the problem is not about the check. I got the failed Stripes warning as well in the raid controller status below "Logical device information"

Comment: I see. Well, you are correct that there are no stripes with RAID-1.